# Не появляется JButton на окне

Tags: java, gui, swing, компоненты

Всем привет, пишу программу на Java Swing, и вот проблема - не появляется JButton.

**Вот код конструктора:**

```java
public REApp() {
        super("Run Executable");
        super.setBounds(500, 500, 300, 200);
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        grid = new GridLayout(6, 3);

        Container cnt = new Container();
        cnt.setLayout(grid);

        test = new JButton("...", new ImageIcon("browse-original.png"));
        test.setDefaultCapable(true);
        test.setVisible(true);
        test.addActionListener(new BrowseEventHandler());

        cnt.add(test);
}
```

Вот окно:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После создания контейнера добавьте его во фрейм

```
super.getContentPane().add(cnt);
```